# ESP8266 fail to connect MQTT broker

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, mqtt

I am using NodeMCU dev board with ESP8266 WIFI.

Every time I try to connect to my local broker it returns this error:

```
failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, my local brokers are Mosquitto and EQMTT. I tried both of them through pubsubclient library and it doesn't connect. Using MQTT Box works connecting to my local brokers. Connecting to my WiFi also works. When I connect to a MQTT broker using pubsubclient e.g. mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883/ it works. It just doesn't seem to work with local broker. This is the code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "mywifi";
const char* password = "password";
const char* mqtt_server = "127.0.0.1";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(D7, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(D7, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is acive low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(D7, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, 75, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("outTopic", msg);
  }
}
```

Note: The brokers are running, I can even connect it through MQTT Box (attached picture).

[image: MQTT Box connection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is not the address of your computer.  That is the address of the "loopback" interface - a virtual interface that allows a device to talk to itself.

That means that when you are using the MQTT server itself you can connect, because it's all the same computer.  However the ESP8266 is trying to connect to itself, not the MQTT server.

You need to replace `127.0.0.1` with the actual IP address of your MQTT server.

The simplest way of getting your computer's IP address is to open a terminal window and type:

```
hostname -I
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Where can I find the actual IP address of my MQTT server?

Comment: type `ip address` in a terminal and find the interface you are connecting with. It'll probably be `192.168.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: Alternatively you can run `hostname -I` (that's a capital i) and it will give you all your non-loopback IP addresses.

Comment: It returned **192.168.100.3**, I have replaced it in my code, but it still shows **rc = 2**. Any ideas? It's only like that using local broker.

Comment: What IP address is your ESP8266 being given?

Comment: ESP8266 is given **192.168.100.12**

Comment: Try running `netstat -an4 | grep 1883 | grep LISTEN` and tell me what it tells you

Comment: Thank you. It suddenly worked, that is after your suggestion to **hostname -I**.

Comment: Can you help me again? It's not working suddenly. It seems to be very inconsistent. I haven't changed the code since yesterday (last time it worked).

Comment: `netstat -an4 | grep 1883 | grep LISTEN` gives me
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11883         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: The last line of that output is mosquitto listening on all interfaces, so that's fine. If it *has* worked, but isn't now, it may be something to do with your network or computer. It wouldn't be your sketch, since that doesn't change.

Comment: How would I able do diagnose it correctly? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WiFi connection.

Comment: However, I would handle your connection differently in your sketch.  Hold on, let me upload an example for you that I am using live in front of me right now (5 channel digital audio mixer controlled by MQTT)...

Comment: Another note, I listed all devices connected to my WiFi network, I tried pinging ALL online ones with their IP Address but it results in `From 192.168.100.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable`. Only the ping to NodeMCU works `64 bytes from 192.168.100.12: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=11.9 ms`. May that be the problem?

Comment: Oh wow really weird! It's connected to MTTQ now. I just let it rest.

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/majenkotech/AmpControl/blob/master/AmpControl.ino - focus on what's in loop - the rest is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: To give you an overview: you don't need to *wait* for a WiFi connection. You just need to see if it is connected or not - and if it is, then check if the MQTT is connected and connect it if it isn't, subscribing once the connection is established

Comment: Hm thanks for the help, but I don't really get the difference, it's basically linear with my logic. I just have trouble getting the MQTT connection, which I suspect has something to do with my WiFi/ host.

Comment: It takes about > 20 of these
`Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds` until it gets connected.

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of (or massively shortening) that 5 second delay.